# How to center align the the first column of the pNiceMatrix?

Tags: alignment, nicematrix

How to center align the the first column of the pNiceMatrix?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
    & V_{\mathrm{X}} & V_{\mathrm{XYZ}} & V_{\mathrm{TK}} \\
V_{\mathrm{X}}& C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \\
V_{\mathrm{XYZ}} & C_1 & C_2 & C_3  \\
V_{\mathrm{TK}} & C_1 & C_2 & C_3  \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command `\Block`: `\Block{n-m}{<content>}` generates a **n** multirow x **m** multicolumn cell (a monocell 1x1 in this case)  centered content.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                                    & V_{\mathrm{X}} & V_{\mathrm{XYZ}} & V_{\mathrm{TK}} \\
    \Block{1-1}{V_{\mathrm{X}}}     & C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \\
    \Block{1-1}{V_{\mathrm{XYZ}}}   & C_1 & C_2 & C_3  \\
    \Block{1-1}{V_{\mathrm{TK}}}    & C_1 & C_2 & C_3  \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```